# Redirecting but need to figure out to ignore a directory in .htaccess in a multisite wordpress structure

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, redirect

Heres the current .htaccess rule we have on our staging server and it works but it breaks the country sites. \

```
RewriteEngine  On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging-test.asmarterplanet.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.staging-test.asmarterplanet.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ibm.com/blogs/think$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Need to figure out a way to ignore the country sites within a multisite Wordpress environment. Only the www.staging-test.asmarterplanet.com directory needs to redirect to the new blogs/think site

These are the sites we need to ignore

```
/es/
/ch/
/se/
/no/
/nl/
/jp/
/dk/
```

This directory is the only site we need to accept the redirect “staging-test.asmarterplanet.com “

Comment: If anyone can provide the the answer ASAP. We have a tight deadline by Oct 6 to push a new site live. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging-test.asmarterplanet.com|www.staging-test.asmarterplanet.com [NC]
 RewriteCond $1 !^(es|ch|se|no|nl|jp|dk)
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*).*$ http://www.ibm.com/blogs/think$0 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The new Rewrite condition checks that the first part of the path does not match any of the specified country paths before allowing the rule.

Comment: BTW - just edited the answer to correct the backreference in the last line.

Comment: Tested locally and it works, write back if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thats the address I get above when I tried a country site.

Comment: That url works for me (does not redirect) when I test. I've updated the 2nd line to improve the regexp but I don't think that is your issue. Being a wordpress site, are there other rewrite rules in the file? Are you clearing browser cache between tests so that the previous 301 response is not being cached?